# What makes scala.util.matching.regex library different from java.util.regex library?

Tags: java, regex, scala

As a Java developer learning Scala, I was surprised to find a [separate Scala library for regular expressions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex). The major difference seems to me to be that a lot of the Scala operations return an Option[String].  Is that the key difference or is there more I'm missing there in how those libraries are used?

Comment: *This class **delegates to the `java.util.regex` package** of the Java Platform. **See the documentation for `java.util.regex.Pattern`** for details about the regular expression syntax for pattern strings.* - so, the syntax is the same. Just in Scala, you can use single backslashes with `"""`-enclosed strings.

Comment: Read the doc for usage in pattern matches, other conveniences. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.util.matching.Regex

Comment: @som-snytt why would the pattern matching and functionality be any different from the java library?  Is there anything Scala specific about those functions other than the single backslash wrinkle?

Comment: Sorry I meant `match` expressions, `val r = "[ab]*".r ; "ba" match { case r() => }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See what it is written in the [`scala.util.matching.Regex` documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex):

> This class *delegates* to the `java.util.regex` package of the Java Platform. See the documentation for `java.util.regex.Pattern` for details about the regular expression syntax for pattern strings.

So, the regex library used is `java.util.regex`, thus, the syntax is the same and all the shortcomings are the same.

Just in Scala, you can use single backslashes inside triple quoted strings.

If you were to compare *methods* that you have in Scala, then there are some differences. A nice method is `findAllIn`/`findAllMatchIn` and some others.

Comment: Are the differences in available methods because methods of the nature of findAllIn/findAllMatchIn make more sense in the context of working with Scala Options?

Comment: Perhaps, they are there for convenience.